# Selecting most recent date per ID for every day

Tags: sql, database

I've checked a few questions about this already but they don't do quite what I want and involve multiple columns and conditions so I'm going to distill it down to its most basic form.

```
SERIAL  DATE_TIME
1       01/01/2015 12:00:00
1       01/01/2015 15:00:00
2       01/01/2015 13:00:00
1       02/01/2015 12:00:00
2       02/01/2015 12:00:00
2       02/01/2015 09:00:00
```

Each serial may have multiple rows in the table and multiple entries per day. I want to return the latest entry per day for each serial. So in this scenario I would want:

```
SERIAL  DATE_TIME
1       01/01/2015 15:00:00
1       02/01/2015 12:00:00
2       01/01/2015 13:00:00
2       02/01/2015 12:00:00
```

Ideally a solution that works with any DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on the *any RDBMS* part, but in T-SQL, and probably many others, you could do this:

```
SELECT Serial, MAX(Date_Time) AS Date_Time
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Serial, CAST(Date_Time AS DATE)
```

From what I can find, it *sounds* like `CAST` is an ANSI standard, so it should work with "everything," but I'm not familiar enough with the standards to give you a definitive answer on that, specifically.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/656c3/2) of it working. Just for good measure, I assume you don't actually need this, but if you want it to look exactly the same as your example (formatting permitting), you could easily append an `ORDER BY Serial, Date_Time` to sort them as you did.

Comment: This works well. The cast seems to cause it not to work.

I'm using oracle so using TO_CHAR (ach_date_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY') seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Will not work on ALL SQL versions. However will work on ones that support WINDOW functions:

```
CREATE TABLE #a
(
    serial INT, date_time DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #a VALUES (1, '01/01/2015 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES (1,       '01/01/2015 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES (2,       '01/01/2015 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES (1,       '02/01/2015 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES (2,       '02/01/2015 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES (2,       '02/01/2015 09:00:00');

SELECT serial, date_time FROM (
SELECT serial, date_time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY serial, CAST(date_time AS DATE)  ORDER BY date_time DESC) row_num
FROM  #a 
) a 
WHERE a.row_num = 1
```

Another option with aggregates:

```
SELECT serial, max_date_time FROM (
SELECT serial, CAST(date_time AS DATE) AS serial_date,
        MAX(date_time) AS max_date_time
FROM  #a 
GROUP BY serial, CAST(date_time AS DATE)
) a
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following query:

```
select serial, max(date_time) from tbl group by serial;
```

Comment: 2 rows will be returned. But in the sample result there are 4 rows.